# NSManagedObject changes do not trigger objectWillChange

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, combine

I have a Core Data model with an entity generated into class `Task`. I am trying to get the Combine publisher `objectWillChange` from the `NSManagedObject` to send (automatically, without manual work), but it won't. The task entity has a `name` attribute.

```swift
let task = Task(context: container.viewContext)

let taskSubscription = task.objectWillChange.sink(receiveValue: { _ in
    print("Task changed")
})

task.name = "Foo"              // WILL NOT trigger
```

If I call send manually, the subscription will work:

```swift
task.objectWillChange.send()   // Will trigger
```

If I replace this with a simple `ObservableObject`, it will work as expected:

```swift
class DummyTask: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String?
}
```

```swift
let dummy = DummyTask()
let dummySubscription = dummy.objectWillChange.sink(receiveValue: { _ in
    print("Dummy changed")
})

dummy.name = "Foo"              // Will trigger
dummy.objectWillChange.send()   // Will trigger
```

Is NSManagedObject bugged? How should I observe the general entity object for changes? How should I get SwiftUI to see them?

This is using Xcode 11.0 and iOS 13.

Comment: Is `name` marked as Published? That's usually the cause when I have problems. I don't think that there is enough here for anyone to help you unfortunately. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-fetchrequest-property-wrapper or https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/blog/ios-development/data-persistence/using-core-data-with-swiftui-introduction/ may help you

Comment: @MichaelSalmon `name` in the `NSManagedObject` is as it is generated from the model definition. When you look at the generated swift file, it is `@NSManaged`. The point here is that these two work differently despite both being `ObservableObject`s.

Comment: I've just started with Core Data and I can't say that I am impressed yet. I am not really sure yet but it appears to me that changes are only triggered when the context is saved. One thing to remember is that an ObservableObject has a publisher called objectWillChange, nothing more. In a normal OO you add \@Published or write your own equivalent, I don't know what \@NSManaged does and I don't think that you should presume that it does what you want. An alternative is to create subclass files and modify them to suit.

Comment: I've gotten to the stage where I am updating entries in Core Data. Updating the data was painless but getting the changes to display took some time. In the end I marked the Core Data instance as an `@ObservedObject` and invoked `objectWillChange.send()` for the instance.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same problem. Sadly, my NSManagedObject can be refreshed by a background synchronization and I haven't found a way to make this work. I will continue using the old Notifications.

Comment: Does it trigger after you save the context?

Answer (score 14):

I believe it is a bug.  There is no point for `NSManagedObject` to conform to `ObservableObject` but unable to mark any property as `@Published`.

While we are waiting Apple to rectify this, I've come across a cleaner solution than @jesseSpencer's suggested one.  The logic behind is the same, by adding a `objectWillChange.send()`, but adding globally into `willChangeValue(forKey key: String)` instead of adding into individual properties.

```
override public func willChangeValue(forKey key: String) {  
    super.willChangeValue(forKey: key)  
    self.objectWillChange.send()  
}
```

Credits: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/121897

Answer (score 6):

My guess is that it is a bug. NSManagedObject conformance to ObservableObject was added in beta 5 which also introduced other significant changes, including deprecation of BindableObject (for replacement by ObservableObject).

See the SwiftUI section:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_ipados_release_notes/ios_13_release_notes)

I ran into the same issue and despite NSManagedObject conforming to ObservableObject, it was not emitting notifications for changes. This might have something to do with NSManagedObject properties needing to be wrapped with @NSManaged which cannot be combined with @Published, while the ObservableObject doc states that, by default, an ObservableObject will synthesize objectWillChange publishers for @Published property changes. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/observableobject

I first tried to get around this by bootstrapping a call to `objectWillChange.send()` in overrides to Key-Value methods in my NSManagedObject subclass, which only resulted in incorrect behavior.

The solution I went with is the simplest and unfortunately maybe the bulkiest if you need to change a lot of codependent properties in your SwiftUI view. But, so far it is working fine for me and maintains use of SwiftUI as intended.

---

In Swift:

1. Create an NSManagedObject subclass for your entity.
2. In that subclass, create setter methods for the properties you wish to change from your SwiftUI views and at the beginning of the method add a call to `objectWillChange.send()`, which should look something like this:

   ```
   func setTitle(_ text: String) {
       objectWillChange.send()

       self.title = text
   }
   ```

---

I only advise this as a temporary workaround, as it is not ideal and hopefully will be addressed soon.

I will be submitting a bug report in FeedbackAssistant and I recommend to anyone else encountering this issue to do the same, so we can get Apple to take another look at this!

Edit:
A warning about @Anthony’s answer:
While the suggested approach does work, be aware that it will not work when changing collection type relationships, i.e. adding an object to an array associated with the NSManagedObject.

Answer (score -2):

To observe `NSManagedObject` changes, please look at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/performing-key-value-observing-with-combine.

Pay attention that, when you use that method in custom class of `UICollectionViewListCell` or `UITableViewCell`, you should override the `prepareForReuse` method and put there alike code:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
   super.prepareForReuse()
   nameObserver?.cancel()
   nameObserver = nil
}
```