# Filtered relationship count not updating in parent view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In my parent view I have the following code:

```
Text(String((todoList.todoItems as! Set<TodoItem>).filter({ $0.checked }).count))
Text("/")
Text(String(todoList.todoItems?.count ?? 0))
```

For example, if I had `checked` off 2 out of 5 tasks, I would get `2/5`.

The first count (with the filter) is not updating when `todoItems` change, but the 2nd one is. If I completely close the app and re-open it the first count does show the correct number.

How do I get the first number to update like the second when the relationship changes, without having to relaunch the app?

Comment: Is `TodoItem` a class or struct?

Comment: It's a CoreData class. There is a one-to-many relationship `todoList` has many `todoItem`. `todoItems` is an `NSSet?`. I'm using a `FetchRequest` to populate the view.

Comment: Ok, since it is a class, you will want to look into `ObservableObject`. Do you want me to provide answer on this to show you exactly what I mean?

Comment: I think the problem is that when the relationship item changes it's not sending the same type of notification to the view as when a new relationship item is added or deleted. Is there a simple way for the `todoItem` to broadcast when it changes to the `todoList` view?

Comment: When I add or delete a relationship item it seems to update the parent view fine. But when I simply change the `checked` status of an item it does not.

Comment: How is `todoList` defined at the top of your `View` struct?

Comment: As a `var`. I tried adding `@ObservableObject` to it but that didn't change anything. I need to figure out how to push changes to the parent view when a relationship item changes.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding a new column called `dateChecked` to the `TodoList` CoreData table. Whenever an item is checked, I simply update that value with the current date and it pushes the changes to the views as desired.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be *exactly* what you needed, but it will give you the general idea.

Here is some example code:

```
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject private var todoList = TodoList()


    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(String(todoList.todoItems?.filter({ $0.checked }).count ?? 0))
            Text("/")
            Text(String(todoList.todoItems?.count ?? 0))
        }
        .onAppear(perform: changeItemAfterSomeSeconds)
    }


    func changeItemAfterSomeSeconds() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            // Updating
            print("Changed!")
            self.todoList.setChecked(to: true, forIndex: 0)
        }
    }
}



class TodoList: ObservableObject {

    @Published var todoItems: [TodoItem]? = [
        TodoItem(name: "Clean house", checked: false),
        TodoItem(name: "Pay bills", checked: false),
        TodoItem(name: "Exercise", checked: true)
    ]

    func setChecked(to bool: Bool, forIndex index: Int) {
        guard todoItems != nil else { return }
        guard 0 ..< todoItems!.count ~= index else { return }

        let current = todoItems![index]
        guard current.checked != bool else { return }

        todoItems![index] = TodoItem(name: current.name, checked: bool)
    }
}


// Your CoreData class (I don't exactly know what it looks like)
class TodoItem {

    let name: String
    let checked: Bool

    init(name: String, checked: Bool) {
        self.name = name
        self.checked = checked
    }
}
```

---

The main challenge of this was making `TodoItem` be a class, as that was one of your requirements. To achieve this, `setChecked(to:forIndex:)` needed to be made.

You can copy and paste this code into an empty SwiftUI project, to see what's happening. So after 3 seconds of the `ContentView` appearing, `changeItemAfterSomeSeconds()` is performed which calls `setChecked(to:forIndex:)` to change it's value. You then see `ContentView` update.

This was all made possible by using `ObservableObject`, which means that the view body should update if the `@Published` property changes.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't declare an observed object for `todoList` in my use case because it is inside of a `ForEach` via `FetchedResults`....sorry I should have specified that. I found a fix though, I just added a date column to the `TodoList` table and I update it when an item is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Its all about you using CoreData. NSObject class has a bug. You can fix it by adding extension to your subclass, as [it was said here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58068446/nsmanagedobject-changes-do-not-trigger-objectwillchange) by @Anthony

```
override public func willChangeValue(forKey key: String) {
    super.willChangeValue(forKey: key)
    self.objectWillChange.send()
}
```

By the way, you can use a computed property instead of NSSet collection like this:

```
public var checkedItems: [CheckItem]{
     let set = toCheck as? Set<CheckItem> ?? []
    return set.filter({$0.checked}).sorted(){$0.wrappedName > $1.wrappedName}
}
```

after that you can use it simply in `ForeEach`.

Another computed property helps to push notification to the parent object:

```
public var checkedTrigger: Bool{
    get{
        checked
    }
    set{
        if let todo = self.toDo {
            todo.willChangeValue(forKey: "checkedItems")
        }
        checked = newValue
    }
}
```

Then just put this new property in a  `Toggle("checked:", isOn: $checkItem.checkedTrigger)`

[image: that's how it works]

Here is DataModel

[image: DataModel]

and full code:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

@objc(ToDoItem)
public class ToDoItem: NSManagedObject , Identifiable{
    public var id = UUID()
}

extension ToDoItem {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<ToDoItem> {
        return NSFetchRequest<ToDoItem>(entityName: "ToDoItem")
    }

    @NSManaged public var title: String?
    @NSManaged public var toCheck: NSSet?
    public var checkList: [CheckItem]{
         let set = toCheck as? Set<CheckItem> ?? []
         return set.sorted(){$0.wrappedName > $1.wrappedName}
    }
    public var checkedItems: [CheckItem]{
         let set = toCheck as? Set<CheckItem> ?? []
        return set.filter({$0.checked}).sorted(){$0.wrappedName > $1.wrappedName}
    }

    override public func willChangeValue(forKey key: String) {
        super.willChangeValue(forKey: key)
        self.objectWillChange.send()
    }
}

// MARK: Generated accessors for toCheck
extension ToDoItem {

    @objc(addToCheckObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToToCheck(_ value: CheckItem)

    @objc(removeToCheckObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromToCheck(_ value: CheckItem)

    @objc(addToCheck:)
    @NSManaged public func addToToCheck(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeToCheck:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromToCheck(_ values: NSSet)

    static func allItemsFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<ToDoItem>{
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<ToDoItem> = ToDoItem.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = []
        return fetchRequest
    }

}

@objc(CheckItem)
public class CheckItem: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
    public var id = UUID()
}

extension CheckItem {
    override public func willChangeValue(forKey key: String) {
        super.willChangeValue(forKey: key)
        self.objectWillChange.send()
    }
    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<CheckItem> {
        return NSFetchRequest<CheckItem>(entityName: "CheckItem")
    }

    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    public var wrappedName: String{
        name ?? "unnamed"
    }
    @NSManaged public var checked: Bool
    public var checkedTrigger: Bool{
        get{
            checked
        }
        set{
            if let todo = self.toDo {
                todo.willChangeValue(forKey: "checkedItems")
            }
            checked = newValue
        }
    }
    @NSManaged public var toDo: ToDoItem?
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: ToDoItem.allItemsFetchRequest()) var toDoItems: FetchedResults<ToDoItem>

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            List{
                ForEach(self.toDoItems){toDoItem in
                    ToDoView(toDoItem: toDoItem)
                }
            }
            HStack{
                 Button("add test items"){
                    let toDo = ToDoItem(context: self.moc)
                    toDo.title = "some title"
                    let check1 = CheckItem(context: self.moc)
                    check1.name = "come item to Check"
                    check1.toDo = toDo
                    let check2 = CheckItem(context: self.moc)
                    check2.name = "another item to Check"
                    check2.toDo = toDo
                }
                Spacer()
                Button("save"){
                    if self.moc.hasChanges{
                        do{
                            try self.moc.save()
                        }catch{
                            print("cant save changes: error.localizedDescription")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ToDoView: View {
    @ObservedObject var toDoItem: ToDoItem
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Text(toDoItem.title!)
            Text("checked: \(toDoItem.checkedItems.count)/\(toDoItem.checkList.count)")
            ForEach(toDoItem.checkList){check in
                CheckView(checkItem: check)
            }

         }
    }
}

struct CheckView: View{
    @ObservedObject var checkItem: CheckItem
    var body: some View{
        HStack{
            Text(checkItem.name ?? "unnamed" )
            Toggle("checked:", isOn: $checkItem.checkedTrigger)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        return ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried `willChangeValue` and it did not work because it didn't seem to fire the view notification update for the PARENT model. I believe that only works on the original model, not its parents. My answer was the cleanest solution I could come up with.

Comment: Yes, that's why I notify parent manual with computed property
```
        if let todo = self.toDo { 
            todo.willChangeValue(forKey: "checkedItems") }
```
 toDo - is a link to a parent object. I added a preview to my answer to show how it works