# Change order of To Many items with CoreData and SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a One-To-Many relationship in CoreData that is one Playlist to many Songs, the songs are a ordered set in the core data class and I store a position attribute with every song to keep track of the order. Here's how i've implemented it:

**Playlist Class:**

```
extension Playlist {

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Playlist> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Playlist>(entityName: "Playlist")
}

@NSManaged public var name: String?
@NSManaged public var numberOfSongs: Int16
@NSManaged public var songs: NSOrderedSet?

public var songsArray: [Song] {

    if let set = self.songs{

        let array = set.sortedArray { (song1, song2) -> ComparisonResult in
            guard let s1 = song1 as? Song, let s2 = song2 as? Song else {
                return ComparisonResult.orderedSame
            }
            if s1.position < s2.position {
                return ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
            } else if s1.position == s2.position {
                return ComparisonResult.orderedSame
            } else {
                return ComparisonResult.orderedDescending
            }
        }
        return array as! [Song]
    } else {
        return []
    }
 }

public var wrappedName: String {
    self.name ?? "Unknown Playlist Name"
}
```

As you can see i sort the songs by their position attribute before returning them in an array to later be viewed and re-ordered with swiftUI.

**Song Class:**

```
extension Song {

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Song> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Song>(entityName: "Song")
}

@NSManaged public var name: String?
@NSManaged public var position: Int16
@NSManaged public var playlist: Playlist?

public var wrappedName: String {
    self.name ?? "Unknown Playlist Name"
}
```

}

**ContentView.swift:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
@FetchRequest(entity: Playlist.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var playlists: FetchedResults<Playlist>

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
         List {ForEach(playlists, id:\.self)
            { playlist in
                 NavigationLink(destination:
                 PlaylistView(songs: playlist.songsArray) ){
                    Text(playlist.wrappedName)
                 }
             }
            .onDelete(perform: deletePlaylist)
        }
         .navigationBarTitle("Playlists")
         .navigationBarItems(trailing:
            Button(action: {
                let newPlaylist = Playlist(context: self.moc)
                newPlaylist.name = "Playlist Name"

                let newSong1 = Song(context: self.moc)
                newSong1.name = "Song_1"
                newSong1.position = 0
                newPlaylist.addToSongs(newSong1)

                let newSong2 = Song(context: self.moc)
                newSong2.name = "Song_2"
                newSong2.position = 1
                newPlaylist.addToSongs(newSong2)

                newPlaylist.numberOfSongs = 2

                try? self.moc.save()

        }) {
            Image(systemName: "plus").imageScale(.large)
        })
    }
}

func deletePlaylist(offsets: IndexSet) {
    for index in offsets {
        let playlist = playlists[index]
        moc.delete(playlist)
    }
    do {
        try moc.save()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

}

**PlaylistView:**

```
struct PlaylistView: View {
@State var songs: [Song]
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc

var body: some View {
    List { ForEach(self.songs, id: \.self)
        { song in
            Text(song.wrappedName)
        }
        .onMove(perform: move)
    }
    .navigationBarTitle(Text(self.songs[0].playlist!.wrappedName))
    .navigationBarItems(trailing:
        Button(action: {

    }) {
        EditButton()
    })

}

func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
    self.songs.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    var counter: Int16 = 0
    for song in self.songs {
        song.position = counter
        counter += 1
    }

    try! self.moc.save()
}
```

}

Now in the PlaylistView when I re-oreder the songs array I update the songs position attributes to reflect the new order (in move()), but now when I back out of PlaylistView back to ContentView, and then go back into PlaylistView the songs are not in the new order. However if I restart the app and go into the playlist the songs are in the correct new order.

From my understanding every time I click on the NavigationLink to PlaylistView the playlist.songsArray should grab the array from the Playlist class attribute where I do the sorting, so I'm confused as to why the songs in PlaylistView aren't sorted.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Check out the xcode project [here](https://github.com/MichaelongII/core-data-swiftui-array-reorder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `Playlist` entity doesn't know about `Songs` to be changed. Make a fix as it shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59557992/12616648) and your `@fetchRequest` will get the notify and refresh the result.

1. make en extension to send objectWillChange notify when you change object

   ```
   extension Playlist{
       override public func willChangeValue(forKey key: String) {
           super.willChangeValue(forKey: key)
           self.objectWillChange.send()
       }
   }
   ```
2. you shoaled manually send playlist changing notification when starts reordering songs:

   ```
   song.playlist?.ObjectWillChange.send()
   ```

   but you'd better group songs somehow to send one notification for one action, not in the loop for every song

Comment: but if I where you, I wouldn't store the order in CoreData. Instead of it, I would make an array with songs ID witch is outside CoreData and use it to sort it somehow. I believe that's could be done and its not correct to start massive database updates to change order.

Comment: Thanks, using willChangeValue worked. And storing the position of each song in CoreData is the only way i've been able to figure out that persists the order.

Comment: I'd suggest you to refactor your data model. Song must not have hard fixed link to one playlist. What if you will need to have two playlists? or five? You will have to store so many songs for that?

Try to store order in playlist property as an array of ID's (not storable with `CoreData`). Then you can make a daughter view, put that array in sort predicate through the `init()` of this View. Inside predicate you could use element of song ID as a sort property. So when you will change sort array, this View will reinit and apply new sort with no database input.

Comment: I agree that a I should change the relationship to many to many to stop redundant songs stored, but I may be missing something here, how is a representation of the order persisted if the Playlist's array of song id's is not stored in CoreData?

Comment: Im not sure how to do it best. I'm still learning. I would store it encoded in Playlist property of Data type. But I'm not sure its a good practice. Do you really need to store the order? Maybe you could store only original order (like order in album or something not depending on playlist), and shuffled order, if you need it, creates at launch.